# How do I get both inputs to work with the search bar?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

At the moment I've got the following code. When a user inerts text into the 'name' & 'sku' inputs, I need it to display the correct div based on the search after the button is clicked.

Below is the jquery & html code being used.

Please assist me with this one, not sure where I went wrong

```js
jQuery($ => {
  var $search = $("#search-form").on('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //$btns.removeClass('active');
    let value = $('#search-name').val();

    $('.box').show().not(function() {
      return new RegExp(value, 'gi').test($(this).find('.name, .sku').text());
    }).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <form id="search-form">
          <input type="text" id="search-name" class="form-control" placeholder="Search name" />
          <input type="text" id="search-sku" class="form-control" placeholder="Search sku" />
          <button type="submit" id="search-button">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row" id="parent">
        <div class="col-md-2 box drink">
          <div class="text-center">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="" />
            <p class="name">Pepsi</p>
            <p class="sku">D-1251</p>
            <p>$ 2,410</p>
            <p class="location">east</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 box drink">
          <div class="text-center">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="" />
            <p class="name">Pepsi</p>
            <p class="sku">D-12w1</p>
            <p>$ 2,410</p>
            <p class="location">north</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 box">
        <center>
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
          <p class="name">Hot Dog </p>
          <p class="sku">11</p>
          <p>$ 2,410</p>
        </center>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 box">
        <center>
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
          <p class="name">Hot Dog 2</p>
          <p class="sku">12</p>
          <p>$ 2,4105</p>
        </center>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 box">
        <center>
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
          <p class="name">Hot Dog 2233</p>
          <p class="sku">13</p>
          <p>$ 2,4103</p>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Console error in the snippet.

Comment: Also, what is meant by `sku`, if user inputs to both, how do you want to filter the items?

Comment: Hey please check this https://jsfiddle.net/7k9mag8s/1/,

Comment: The products SKU number basically

Comment: If a user searches using the first input and submits it will filter per keyword. However, I want them to be able to search using both inputs. The first would be the name of the product and second would be the products SKU number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each input in your form call a function `filter()` will achieve the desired result.

```
jQuery($ => {
  var $search = $("#search-form").on('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    filter($('#search-name').val(), $('#search-sku').val());
  });
});

function filter(name, sku) {
  $('.box').show().not(function() {
    return new RegExp(name, 'gi').test($(this).find('.name').text()) && new RegExp(sku, 'gi').test($(this).find('.sku').text());
  }).hide();
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks! This worked until I made changed to the HTML code and it stopped filtering correctly. is there any other way?

Comment: What changes did you make?

Comment: basically just added more products to the page and changed a few SKU's

Comment: Are you adding those products dynamically? Should work if it was only that.

Comment: My bad, it was working but I found a slight glitch, if the SKU is the same in 2 divs it will display both even if the 'name' field is different. It should just display the one searched

Comment: You can test it out here by searching name: "Test" + SKU: "cape" https://jsfiddle.net/4hnycgub/

Comment: Please consider my edit. I updated `filter()` with two parameters and added a regex check for both `name` and `sku` so that everything works as expected.

Comment: Genius! Thank you sir